# Eclipse почему-то не видит драйвер postgrSql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, eclipse

Недавно решил попробовать попользоваться eclipse и столкнулся с тем, что переходя на вкладку выбора драйвера для postgreSQL, я ничего не вижу, и что самое досадное, я не могу выбрать драйвер, пройдя по каталогам: кнопки не активны. Прошу помочь тех, кто с этим сталкивался. Буду очень благодарен.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в том, что окно открылось сжатым и поэтому оно не показывало драйвер. Я потянул за грань окна, расширил его, и драйвер внезапно появился.